# Rearrange page numbers - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a follow-up of: [Rearrange page numbers for printing a book](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189288/rearrange-page-numbers-for-printing-a-book)

**Input:**

- Total pages of a book: `int`
- Pages per booklet: `int` (divisible by 4 evenly)

**Processing:**

Rearrange the pages in each booklet to follow a specific format, [n, f, f+1, n-1], where n is the last page of the booklet, and f is the first.

**Output:**

Print a list/tuple of the rearranged integers

**Bugs:**

If pages is not a multiple of 4 the last booklet (list that get processed by `arrange_booklet()`) always has errors at the end.

**Misc:**

int pages will generally be a large number (50~500). I wrote the program because my printer software doesn't allow me to just print the pages in this order. I have to manually type every integer, comma-separated. Which would obviously get tedious very quickly.

```
from math import ceil


# f is the first page (smallest input integer), n is the last (largest)
def arrange_booklet(f, n):
    '''Creates a list by using the page # order formula.'''
    _ = list()
    while n > f:
        _.extend([n, f, f+1, n-1])
        f += 2
        n -= 2
    return _


def make_book():
    '''Combines all the lists into one and returns the result.'''
    pages = list(range(1, int(input("Enter a number of pages: "))+1))
    while True:
        len_booklet = int(input(
            "Enter booklet length, must be a multiple of four: "))
        if len_booklet % 4 == 0:
            break
    book = list()  # permanent list, to be returned
    _ = list()  # temporary list, to populate permanent list
    for page in pages:
        _.append(page)
        if page % len_booklet == 0:
            _ = arrange_booklet(_[0], _[-1])
            book.extend(_)
            _.clear()
    # the last booklet, if pages % 4 != 0, is still in the temp list and broke
    # out of the loop it has to be handled separately below, or it will never
    # reach the book
    if _:
        _ = arrange_booklet(_[0], _[-1])
        book.extend(_)
    print(book)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_book()
```

Comment: Just realized i removed the ceil function in the program but forgot to remove the import statement.. Just ignore that please

Comment: Running the code with 95 and 16 as input, I get the output (at the end) `95,
 81,
 82,
 94,
 93,
 83,
 84,
 92,
 91,
 85,
 86,
 90,
 89,
 87,
 88,
 88]`. Is this desired behaviour? 88 is repeated.

Comment: Apparently you have some kind of affinity for `_`. Any reasons why you're using that instead of a reasonable named variable? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Whislt the code looks better and is more documented, I am disappointed to see that my main point from previous comment was fully ignored. ..

Comment: HJPotter, that is the bug, it is not intended behavior and I don't know how to fix it. яүυк The _ lists were just temporary so I didn't see a point in naming them, If I did I would've named them temp. @Josay Sorry I tried to take your advice fully into consideration. The only advice i explicitly left out was writing a test because I couldn't figure out how. I tried figuring out what you did but I have no experience with dictionaries/sets. I did test various numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## Functions

you should split a lot more of the small pieces of code to separate functions, For example getting and parsing the input has no place in the `make_book`

## Generators

Instead of using temporary lists, using generators is a lot cleaner.

so instead of

```
def my_func():
    _ = []
    for i in range(10):
        _.append(i**2)
    return _
```

with a generator this becomes:

```
def my_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i**2
```

This is a lot cleaner, and easier to maintain.

## Assembling the booklet

instead of iterating over the indices `f` and `n`, you can use a `collections.deque`and use `pop` and `popleft`

```
from collections import deque
def assemble_booklet(pages):
    """assembles the booklet according to the order [-1, 0, 1, -2] and going in.

    Assumes an iterable with the length a multiple of 4"""
    pages = deque(pages)
    assert not len(pages) % 4, 'booklet length, must be a multiple of 4'
    while pages:
        selection = pages.pop(), pages.popleft(), pages.popleft(), pages.pop()
        yield from selection
```

again, the generator style allows us to express this a lot clearer than using the intermediary lists

## grouping in pages

grouping the pages can be easily done with the `grouper` itertools [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks

    grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    """
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Then:

```
for page in pages:
    _.append(page)
    if page % len_booklet == 0:
        _ = arrange_booklet(_[0], _[-1])
        book.extend(_)
        _.clear()
```

becomes:

```
def make_book(pages, booklet_length):
    '''Combines all the lists into one and returns the result.'''
    assert not booklet_length % 4, 'booklet length, must be a multiple of 4'
    for group in grouper(pages, booklet_length, fillvalue='blank'):
        yield tuple(assemble_booklet(group))
        # yield from assemble_booklet(group) # dependent on the output you want
```

If you want the pages in 1 long list instead of separated per booklet, you can change the last line of `make_book` to `yield from assemble_booklet(group)`

And in effect, this is the whole code for this method, that gets an iterable of pages, and form booklets out of them

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pages = range(1, 16)
    booklet_length = 8
    result = list(make_book(pages, booklet_length))
    print(result)
```

> ```
> [(8, 1, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5), ('blank', 9, 10, 15, 14, 11, 12, 13)]
> ```

Comment: What's happening in deque(pages). And does the yield statement below selection yield each page that is popped from the queue as it's popped?

Comment: a `deque` is a kind of queue, a collection that allows easy adding and removing on either side. This could work with a list using `pop(0)` and `pop(-1)`, but is more natural in a deque. Since`zip_longest` yields tuples, `pages` needs to be put in another container anyway, so we might as well use the correct one. The `yield from iterable` is the same a `for i in iterable; yield i`

Answer (score 0):

@Josay This is the best that I can get the code to be. If I have still ignored your main point then I don't understand what your main point is, please elaborate.

**MEMORY:**

I feel like the arrange_booklet function uses much more memory than necessary.

**BUGS:**

I think I finally managed to figure out the bug where extraneous values appear at the end if pages wasn't a multiple of len_booklet

**CHANGES:**

- Added `test()` function that confirms if the book is the correct length
- Removed inputs from functions
- Moved some code from the old `make_book()` function and revised it, created an 
  independent function named `grouper()`
- Combined what was rest of `arrange_booklet()` and `make_book()` into the new 
  `arranged_booklet()`
- Inputs are behind an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard

```
import itertools
import random


def grouper(pages, len_booklet, fillvalue=None):
    '''pages is an iterable, len_booklet is an int
    Creates "groups" of len_booklet length out of pages.'''
    args = [iter(pages)] * len_booklet
    result = list(itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue))
    for group in result:
        yield list(group)


def arrange_booklet(grouped_book, len_booklet):
    '''grouped book is an list, len_booklet is an in
    Arranges grouped_book into the proper format.'''
    for booklet in grouped_book:
        while None in booklet:
            booklet.remove(None)
        n = booklet[-1]
        f = booklet[0]
        # beginning of special case
        if len(booklet) <= len_booklet:
            while len(booklet) > 4:
                yield [n, f, f+1, n-1]
                booklet = booklet[2:-2]
                f += 2
                n -= 2
            if f == n:
                yield [f]
            elif f == n-1:
                yield [n, f]
            elif f == n-2:
                yield [n, f, f+1]
            else:
                yield [n, f, f+1, n-1]
        # end of special case
        else:
            while n > f:
                yield [n, f, f+1, n-1]
                f += 2
                n -= 2


def test():
    for i in range(100):
        len_booklet = random.randrange(4, 256, 4)
        pages = range(1, random.randint(4, 400))
        while pages[-1] < len_booklet:
            pages = range(1, random.randint(4, 400))
        booklets = list(grouper(pages, len_booklet))
        arranged_booklets = list(arrange_booklet(booklets, len_booklet))
        book = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arranged_booklets))
        print("pages : {}\nlen_booklet : {}\n".format(len(pages), len_booklet)
              , end='')
        if len(book) != len(pages):
            print("Error!!!\n", len(book), len(pages))
            break
        else:
            print("All's good\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_or_main = input("Do you want to run a test? (y/n)")
    if test_or_main == "n":
        print("Running main program...")
        pages = range(1, int(input("Enter a number of pages: "))+1)
        while True:
            len_booklet = int(input(
                "Enter booklet length, must be a multiple of four: "))
            if len_booklet % 4 == 0 and len_booklet <= len(pages):
                break
        booklets = list(grouper(pages, len_booklet))
        arranged_booklets = list(arrange_booklet(booklets, len_booklet))
        book = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arranged_booklets))
        print(book)
    else:
        print("Running a test...")
        test()
```